# CSS applying header div color to following div for no reason

Tags: css

I've got an events page with a navy background color applied to my header divs. However all the following event divs are also appearing in navy. I can't find the issue in Inspector and can't replicate the problem when I try it in jsfiddle.

```
<style>
.event-list-header {
    background-color: #2e3a62;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
        
.event-list-header h2{margin:0;padding:0;font-size:18px;}
</style>

<div class="event-list-header"><h2>Monday, October 12, 2020</h2></div>
<div class="event">
  <div class="event-list-date col-md-3"><strong>Oct 12</strong></div>
  <div class="event-content col-md-9">...</div>
  <div class="eventimespan">10 a.m. - 11 a.m.</div>
</div>
```

working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/opera13/1nwbLqex/

Can anyone tell me where I've gone astray?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce that on MS Edge Version 85.0.564.70 (Official build) (64-bit) and macOS Catalina 10.15.7. The provided website shows the problem, but the JSFiddle and provided code don't seem to have it.

Comment: Looks like it was caused by the floats coming in from the Bootstrap stylesheet. Both answers were helpful. Thank you folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `.event`. It has a height of zero because it only contains floated elements. Adding `overflow: auto;` to the parent of the floated elements helps to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

add to your css display:inline-block; and width:100%;`.event-list-header { background-color: #2e3a62; color: #fff; padding: 5px 10px; display:inline-block; width:100%; }`